# Dynamics Importing Option Set Values that were Deleted

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I added two values in an option set field on the production system (on premise Dynamics solution). I realized the right way would be to first introduce the two values into the option set on Dev, then export the solution as managed, and import it into production.

Now when I try to import the managed solution, I'm getting an error:

- An error has occurred. {1}{0}

I believe it's because I had created those first values before in Dynamics, since Dynamics only does soft deletes.

I'm wondering should I go to the StringMapBase table and force delete those option set values, in order for the import to work.

Answer (score 2):

You added those options as unmanaged customizations, so you should be able to delete them in production using the regular customization tooling.

Answer (score 0):

Playing with managed solution is dangerous. That's why I always work unmanaged. I would suggest you to recreate the component manually with the same name or to copy your production database in dev.